# No Method Error in Users#show undefined method `following' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project similar to a twitter clone. I've looked around for others with the same error and haven't been able to find another example of this problem. However, I am running into an error that is the following:

```
undefined method `following' for #<User:0x000055ae42d0d158
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
app/views/shared/_stats.html.erb:5:in 

`_app_views_shared__stats_html_erb__231770652215433765_47103466733040'
    app/views/users/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___1734427599225406369_47103466794880'
Here is user model:
```

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      <%= @user.following.count %>
    </strong>
    following
  </a>
  <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @user.followers.count %>
    </strong>
    followers
  </a>
</div>
```

And place where second error is on 11 row:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if logged_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
  end

    # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

end
```

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def self.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def self.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated, true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest, User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

 # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

 # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  # Defines a proto-feed.
  # See "Following users" for the full implementation.
  def feed
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

  private

  # Converts email to all lower-case.
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end

end
```

And here is Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

And this is my db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_07_112022) do

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "picture"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "follower_id"
    t.integer "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated", default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: As Bartosz says, your user simply doesn't have such method (`following`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In source that you provided, `User` model has neither `.followers` nor `.following` methods.

Proper associations can be defined through dual `has many` association with  `Relationship` model.

```
  has_many :relationships_as_follower, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: "Relationship"
  has_many :relationships_as_followed, foreign_key: :followed_id, class_name: "Relationship"

  has_many :followers, through: :relationships_as_followed, source: :follower
  has_many :following, through: :relationships_as_follower, source: :followed
```

Consider renaming `following` and `followed` to something else, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Now I'm getting error "ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError in StaticPages#home (Could not find the source association(s) "following" or :following in model Relationship. Try 'has_many :following, :through => :relationships_as_followed, :source => <name>'. Is it one of follower or followed?)"

Comment: @OrkoElvis sorry, I didn't notice that only `followers` worked without explicit `source` provided. Also `through` values had to be switched. Updated my answer, should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much, dude :)))))